# php Yii framework job market?

Tags: codeigniter, yii, php

I have used codeigniter for few of my projects in my portfolio and currently seeking a job opportunities. However, I heard yii is a very nice and high demanded php framework in the market now. Is that true? Should I turn my attention to yii or keep building more codeigniter projects in my portfolio for my first web developer job? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you guys intent to close my question. Please advice me the right stackExchange site to post. I couldn't find the right one.

Comment: Jerry, this seems more of a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Atif I don't know, it might still be off-topic on programmers. Off-topic topics listed there include "what language you should learn next, including which technology is better" and "résumé help".

Comment: true, but StackOverflow isn't for career-advice either

Comment: @Atif I know. I'm saying it doesn't fit on either site, and it may not belong on any StackExchange site.

Comment: aw....so where can I ask my question. I appreciate you guys helping me out instead of simply hit 'close'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this does not fit here but what i have learned that since 4-5 months industry here have started working on `Yii`. I have been working on Yii since 4 months it is easy and supports Rapid Application Development.

Moreover performance may be key factor but to me its time to development that this framework allows you. I have worked on CI but Yii is far more ahead of that. provides you nice JQuery implemenation does Ajax validations for you and much more.

```
I recommend it 100%.
```

If you see what is in market you may not be able to learn whole things and some how things keep changing once COBOL was famous but now........... so basically on everything I guess factor overrides is Ease and Rapid Application Developement these are provided by `Yii`